# Cannot send email in ICEmobile project

Tags: android-emulator, notifications, smtp, gmail, icepush

I just started to delve into ICEsoft. I have an ICEmobile project in which I try to implement notification sending to users. I use Tomcat 7, ICEmobile 1.1, ICEfaces 3, and my IDE is Eclipse Juno 4.2.
Here are some code snippets for rendering messages:

```
    /** from NotificationBean class (ApplicationScoped) **/
    // render group is the current session id.
    public String renderGroup = "renderGroup";

    public NotificationBean() {
        PushRenderer.addCurrentSession(renderGroup);
    }

    /** from NotificationController class (ViewScoped) **/
    NotificationBean notifBean = (NotificationBean)FacesUtils.getManagedBean("notificationBean");
    public void sendPriorityPushMessage(ActionEvent event) {
        final PushMessage myMessage = new PushMessage(notifBean.getSubject(), notifBean.getMessage());
        final PortableRenderer portable = PushRenderer.getPortableRenderer();
        ...
        portable.render(notifBean.renderGroup, myMessage);
        ...

    }
```

I've configured SMTP setting in my web.xml in such a way:

smtp.host: smtp.gmail.com

smtp.from: myaccount@gmail.com

smtp.port: 465

smtp.user: myaccount@gmail.com

smtp.password ...

smtp.security: SSL

smtp.verify-server-certificate - false

I am testing all this on an Android emulator, in ICEmobile Container (4.1, 16 + Google APIs). There I unchecked C2DM Notify property and in "Email Notification" entered my email address.

With that code I cannot send email. I get such an error:

```
WARNING: Failed to send email message.
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at org.icepush.EmailNotificationProvider$SendMessage.run(EmailNotificationProvider.java:138)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:507)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
```

Do I miss something? I tried to configure my Tomcat, but don't know how to do it properly - maybe the cue is in that?

Thanks in advance,
Irina

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that problem by updating my mail.jar. Mine was too old.